# how to turn off differential loading in Angular v8?

Tags: angular

Angular-CLI v8 implemented differential loading.
But I don't need files built by es5.
I want to decrease deploy quantity.

I tried below. But CLI has generated es5 files.

- set `es5browsersupport: false` in angular.json, and got error.
- exclude Chrome 41, IE 9-11 and ie_mob 11 from browserList.

Comment: A bug report to @angular/cli: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14991

Answer (score 28):

In Angular 8 the file browserlist have to be in project root folder. Following entries were needed on my project to disable differential loading:

```
> 0.5%
last 2 versions
Firefox ESR
not dead
not IE 9-11
not samsung 4
not android 4.4.3-4.4.4
not last 2 ie_mob versions
not last 2 op_mini versions
not last 2 op_mob versions
not last 2 baidu versions
not last 2 kaios versions
not last 2 and_uc versions
not last 2 and_qq versions
not last 2 edge versions
not chrome 49
```

Comment: works for me on Angular 8.0.1 and `not last 2 edge versions` in not needed because Edge seems to support es2015.
https://caniuse.com/#search=es6

Comment: @Y.M., at the moment, @angular/cli does not consider latest Edge (i.e., Edge 18) to be es2015-modules compliant: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14580

Comment: working in angular 12

Answer (score 19):

None of these answers worked for me on `@angular/cli 8.3.8`. Using the `npx browserslist` I could see that there were more browsers in the list than these StackOverflow answers were up-to-date for.

To keep it simple and ensure differential loading doesn't try to build for `es5`, you can set your `browserslist` to use just 1 older (but still `es6/es2015` compliant) browser version

```
# we only want es2015 compliant browsers https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6
# just use one as representative for all
Chrome >= 61
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me turn off differential loading for es5 in Angular 9RC.
I also set tsconfig.json:
compilerOptions:{
"target": "es2015",
 "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ], }

Comment: Es5 bundles startet do reappear after update to ng12 - no changes to browserlist or target. So I also go with this workaround.

Comment: **Thanks! This cut my build time by 20% from 5 minutes to 4 minutes or less by skipping over "ES5 differential loading".** Can't believe they didn't provide a simple switch to turn ES5 off instead of making us say "We won't support browsers older than this."

Answer (score 12):

I succeeded to build without es5 files in Angular v8-rc4.

set like below in browserList to make `isEs5SupportNeeded` false in [build-angular](https://github.com/alan-agius4/angular-cli/blob/5b26a39ba83e0358785aab822a63d9e7f0cc2624/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/utils/differential-loading.ts#L29).

```
> 0.5%
last 2 versions
Firefox ESR
not dead
not samsung 4
not android 4.4.3-4.4.4
not last 2 IE versions
not last 2 ie_mob versions
not last 2 op_mini versions
not last 2 op_mob versions
not last 2 baidu versions
not last 2 kaios versions
not last 2 and_uc versions
not last 2 and_qq versions
not last 2 edge versions
```

refer to this list.
https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module

Comment: With exact same list I still get polyfills-es5 generated. Did you tried this with Angular 8 final?

Comment: @robert, You probably have this problem because at the moment @angular/cli does not consider latest Edge (i.e., Edge 18) to be es2015-modules compliant: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14580.

Answer (score 9):

Fastest solution: Switch back to `es5` as compilation target in your `tsconfig.json`.

```
"compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "target": "es5"
        ...
}
```

As mentioned on Angular official documentation (https://angular.io/guide/deployment#differential-loading):

> To explicitly disable differential loading:
>
> - Enable the dead or IE browsers in the browserslist config file by removing the not keyword in front of them.
> - Set the target in the compilerOptions to es5.

Comment: Maybe the OP wanted to turn off ES5 and switch fully to ES6 (ES2015) only.

Answer (score 8):

I was able to solve for my project using Angular 8.1.1 by adding the "browserslist" key in `package.json`. (Placed at top level, same as "name", "dependencies", etc.)

```
 "browserslist": [
    "last 2 Chrome versions"
  ]
```

This case works in specific cases where you only need the app to work in Chrome. If you need more browser compatibility check out other options in the implementation docs here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserslist

Answer (score 8):

Simply specify in .browserslistrc

```
supports es6-module
```

Comment: This is the only, truly, correct answer!

Comment: I was upgrading from Angular 8 to Angular 10.  The only thing that would make my projects compile was to set the target to ES5, this got the job done, though I've done many of the steps above, in previous answers, this one was the one that broke through the error.

Answer (score 6):

For a 2021 answer (Angular 11 - 12.1.1)
This browserslist within my package.json file stopped building `ES5` bundles.

At the time of writing, the browsers which fit these descriptions can handle my `tsconfig`'s build target.

```
scripts: {...
dependencies: {...
devDependencies: {...
...
"browserslist": [
    "last 5 Chrome versions",
    "last 5 ChromeAndroid versions",
    "last 3 Safari versions",
    "last 3 iOS versions",
    "last 5 Firefox versions",
    "last 5 FirefoxAndroid versions",
    "Firefox ESR",
    "last 2 Edge versions",
    "not dead"
]
```

> Run `npx browserslist` in your project directory to see your project’s
> target browsers.
>
> This CLI tool is built-in and available in any project
> with Autoprefixer.

As you can see, there is a huge advantage to dropping outdated browsers.

```
Initial ES5 Total | 1.12 MB 
Initial ES2020 Total | 960.50 kB
```

Comment: If you're working with a codebase that started with Angular <=8 and was progressively updated to Angular 10+, you may find that the compiler suddenly starts to generates ES5 modules for differential loading. In this case, after you have modified `tsconfig.json` & `.browserslistrc` files as per comments here, make sure to update npm packages `browserslist` & `caniuse-lite` to their latest versions. This will ensure that the latest Angular compiler's is-differential-loading-required auto-detection mechanism works as expected with the latest capability definitions in `caniuse-lite` package.

Comment: Only thing that worked for me in angular 12 ie, adding browserlist to package.json.

Answer (score 3):

in tsconfig.json set target to es2015 if you want to compile for new version
first or set it to es5 to disable diffrential loading

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "target": "es2015",
    ...
}
```

and in angular.json change es5BrowserSupport to false

```
project => app => architect => build => 
"options": {
    ...
    "es5BrowserSupport": false
    ...
}
```

Comment: This property was removed in ng 10

Answer (score 2):

At the moment many people have es5 bundle generated because @angular/cli does not consider latest Edge (i.e., Edge 18) to be es2015-modules compliant: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14580.

<s>A dirty fix is to exclude Edge from the list of browsers you support (in the `browserslist` file).</s> This problem should be fixed if you upgrade to @angular/cli 8.1.0.

Answer (score 2):

try changing the `tsconfig.json` target from `es2015`back down to `es5`, this disables differential loading.

Answer (score 0):

Can add below env variables to disable differential loading features. The below works for Windows

`"build:prod": "set NG_BUILD_DIFFERENTIAL_FULL=true && ng build --prod",`

For Mac

`"build:prod": "NG_BUILD_DIFFERENTIAL_FULL=true; ng build --prod",`

Comment: NG_BUILD_DIFFERENTIAL_FULL does not disable builds for differential loading. It changes how the two builds are built. In angular 8.3, the es2015 are "directly downleved to ES5, instead of rebuilt from scratch" https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2019/08/22/angular-cli-8.3/

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
> 5.0%
last 1 edge versions
```

will do the job