# Angular 8 CLI: Disable differential loading in development serve

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, angular-cli, ecmascript-5

Since upgrading to Angular 8, differential loading has been enabled by default in our projects and resulting in a polyfill for both ES5 and ES2015. While I welcome this change very much, is there any way to force ES2015 mode in development mode? I'm trying to shave off any second from the initial and incremental build times, which are exceeding 40 / 8 seconds respectively.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56197896/2050306

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14911

Answer (score 3):

ES5 is disabled by default for development with `ng serve`.

> In Angular CLI version 8 and higher, differential loading is enabled by default for the ng build command. **The ng serve, ng test, and ng e2e commands, however, generate a single ES2015 build which cannot run in older browsers that don't support the modules, such as IE 11.**

*[Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#local-development-in-older-browsers)*

I belive it is also disabled for `ng build --watch`, but I found no reference if this is intened behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

> Differential loading can be explicitly disabled if it causes unexpected issues or you need to target ES5 specifically for legacy browser support.
>
> To explicitly disable differential loading:
>
> Enable the dead or IE browsers in the browserslist config file by removing the not keyword in front of them.Set the target in the compilerOptions to es5.

https://angular.io/guide/deployment#configuring-differential-loading