# building angular app with ng build throws error process.umask is not a function

Tags: angular, build

Im  running the ng build -- prod command on my angular project but im getting the following error. Any idea what I could do?  Thanks!!!

Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading...
An unhandled exception occurred: process.umask is not a function
See "/private/var/folders/m6/8xybphq51fn989xcx92d_w340000gn/T/ng-Taa9uW/angular-errors.log" for further details.
ng build --prod[62413]: ../src/node_worker.cc:101:node::worker::Worker::Worker(node::Environment *, Local, const std::string &): Assertion `(uv_loop_init(&loop_)) == (0)' failed.

Answer (score 3):

I change in tsconfig.json under compilerOptions the line `"target": "es2005"` to `"target": "es5"`.

That post helps me:
[how to turn off differential loading in Angular v8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56197896/how-to-turn-off-differential-loading-in-angular-v8)

Answer (score 0):

reinstalling node worked for me

> nvm install node