# Angular 10 generate only es2015 files

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to generate only the es2015 files on the angular build, so I have changed my .browserslistrc file accordingly. But ng build always generates both the es2015 and es5 files. Below are my tsconfig.app.json, tsconfig.base.json and .browserslistrc files.

> tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["googlemaps"]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": true
  },
  "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "src/typings.d.ts"]
}
```

> tsconfig.base.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./scripts/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "types": [
      "googlemaps"
    ]
  }
}
```

> .browserslistrc

```
last 2 Chrome versions
last 2 ChromeAndroid versions
last 2 Safari versions
last 2 iOS versions
last 2 Firefox versions
last 2 FirefoxAndroid versions
last 2 Edge versions
```

> npx browserslist shows below output

[image]

Comment: please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56197896/how-to-turn-off-differential-loading-in-angular-v8

Comment: @DucNguyen Thanks :). Adding "browserslist": [ "last 2 Chrome versions" ] to package json fixed the issue